# Select2 - Add searchbox to multiple select instead of inline search

Tags: select, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm busy implementing the Select2 library as an Angular2 component. Right now, I have the Select2 container for multiple selects with tags fully styled. However there is one thing left that I can't seem to find. Instead of making the search inline ( on tags ), I'd like to have a dedicated position for my search box, like there would be when the select would be a single select.

Below some photo's.

[Multiple select with inline search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdiZ5.png)
[Single search with dedicated search box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOXt2.png)